# How to decrease boot time in Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid

My Ionic app is taking around **10 seconds** to load the home screen. It remains on Splash screen for around 10 secs. I have tried the following

- **Optimized the images by compression**
- **Source code minification**
- **Disabled Native scroll**
- **Added Crosswalk**
- **Tried adding `async` to some scripts**

but still **no improvements**. Plz suggest me what can I do to make it **load fast**.

**PS: Working fine on IOS taking around 5 secs for first run after that around 2 secs only.**

Answer (score 0):

you just add following line in your config file. you can also decrease splash screen delay.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
```

i hope its work for you.